# How to make two different notifications to notify at two different time?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I would like to create two different notifications (with different title, text, content...etc.) and issue them at two different time of the day.

That's my MainActivity code:

First notification:

```
 receiver.putExtra("which", 0);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CountdownActivity.this, 0, receiver,0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, after30minutes, pendingIntent);
```

Second notification:

```
receiver.putExtra("which", 1);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CountdownActivity.this, 0, receiver,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (endInSeconds*1000)-(1800*1000), pendingIntent2);
```

receiver is an intent between this class and receiver class (that extends broadcast receiver).
That's my NotificationReceiver (extends BroadcastReceiver) code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
     Intent intentService = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
     context.startService(intentService);
}
```

Finally, that's my NotificationService (extends Service) code:

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        //preparazione variabili
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        countdown = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), CountdownActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, countdown,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //costruzione notifica
        if(intent.getExtras().getInt("which") == 0) //1 ora
        {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("1 ora")
                    .setContentText("contenuto")
                    .setLargeIcon(bm)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
        }
        else if(intent.getExtras().getInt("which") == 1) //mezz'ora
        {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Ole")
                    .setContentText("contenuto")
                    .setLargeIcon(bm)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
        }

        //operazioni finali
        countdown.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

EDIT
I solved putting a countdown in my NotificationService class.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);`, you should pass a unique ID instead of `0`. So, for instance, it would be sufficient to pass the value of `intent.getExtras().getInt("which")`. Mostly, I declare these IDs as a `public static final int` in the class.

As the docs state for `NotificationManager#notify(int, android.app.Notification)`:

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html